# Double click in Karate

Tags: karate

Doesn't work double click in Karate. I use this command * mouse('#myBtn').doubleClick() and nothing happens. What is the problem? I'm sure that the locator (XPath) of the button is correct - it works with single click.

Comment: maybe it is a bug in karate. provide info for others to replicate this or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue